# How to register a component and property editor at run-time?

Tags: delphi, vcl

After much searching, it looks like I have to assign `RegisterComponentsProc` and `RegisterPropertyEditorProc`, which I have done.

However, I thought that I could call my design time Register function, i.e. `<myComponentUnit>.Register();`.

When I do I get stack overflow, because, well ...

```
procedure myComponentUnit.Regiter;
begin
  RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(Integer), 
                         TMyComponent, 'myProperty',   TMyProperty);
```

end;

```
procedure RegisterPropertyEditor(PropertyType: PTypeInfo;
  ComponentClass: TClass; const PropertyName: string;
  EditorClass: TPropertyEditorClass);
begin
  if Assigned(RegisterPropertyEditorProc) then
    RegisterPropertyEditorProc(PropertyType, ComponentClass, PropertyName,
      EditorClass);
end;
```

So, I call .Register();
which calls   RegisterPropertyEditor()
which call      RegisterPropertyEditorProc()
which calls       RegisterPropertyEditor()   <=== aaargh!!

So, what should I have in the body of my RegisterPropertyEditorProc ?

After further searching, it looks like I want to call `DesignEditors.RegisterPropertyEditor()` directly, but it is not in the interface section ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no point in trying to register a property editor at run-time, as it is not usable at run-time to begin with.  It is only usable within the IDE during design-time.

Comment: not if you write your own property editor, I hope.  Unfortunately, there is no answer at http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/property.htm or http://delphi.about.com/library/bluc/text/uc092501a.htm etc

Comment: Again, property editors (and component editors) are only usable at design-time, as they are implemented in design-time packages only, and you are not allowed to use design-time packages in run-time executables.  What are you trying to accomplish in the first place?

Comment: Tl;dr - a run time Object Inspector, where I specify the properties.  Longer: Seen years later, and I am trying to achieve the same thing again. Plus ca change. To keep it simple, let's call it a drawing program.  At run-time, users drag components from a tool bar, just as we do in the IDE when designing a form. I want to have a floating toolbar, at run tine, that looks like the Object Inspector and allows the user to examine and manipulate the properties of an on-screen object, where my code defines which properties . Any hints, @Remy

Comment: @Mawg: You can't use native Delphi property/component editors in that manner.  The runtime support simply is not implemented.  However, there are plenty of third-party runtime Object Inspectors available if you search around.

Comment: Thanks, Remy. I guess that I will create my own. A floating  panel with two columns, the left for property names and the right for values, click to change.

Answer (score 5):

Delphi does not include the source for the DesignEditors unit; its implementation is provided solely in the DesignIDE package. That package has access to IDE internals, such as the list of registered property editors. The IDE assigns values to the RegisterComponentsProc and RegisterPropertyEditorProc callback functions. As you noticed, RegisterPropertyEditor calls RegisterPropertyEditorProc. The IDE provides its own function to handle that event.

If you want to register a property editor at run time, then your program plays the role of the IDE. You need to provide implementations for those callback functions to register the property-editor classes with your own property-editing framework. You could probably just keep everything in a simple list. Then, when you want to know what kind of editor to display for a certain type of property, consult the list to find the best match.

You're correct that you should call your units' Register procedures. But that's how you *initiate* the registration process, not how you *implement* it. That part's up to you; Delphi doesn't provide any of this for you.

Comment: I had, at the time, been reading [this](http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/property.htm), which mentions those functions which would have to be implemented. On reflection, I think that it might be simpler just two have a panel with two columns, the left for property names and the right for values, click to change. I am Googling around for tutorials. Do you know of any?

Comment: Use a `TValueListEditor`. Comes standard with Delphi since 2005, or perhaps earlier.